# WCF namedpipe callback timeout exception

Tags: wcf, exception, timeout

I am using WCF for sending and getting data to and from 2 different win form applications running in the same machine. I am using namedpipe and duplexchannel. My client side implementation is shown below.

```
InstanceContext myContext = new InstanceContext(this);

NetNamedPipeBinding nb = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
nb.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5000000;
nb.MaxBufferSize = 500000;
nb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 500000;
nb.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

DuplexChannelFactory<IService> myProxy = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(myContext, nb, new EndPointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyService"));

IService myServiceClient = myProxy.CreateChannel();
```

And Server side implementation is shown below:

```
NetNamedPipeBinding np = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
np.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5000000;
np.MaxBufferSize = 500000;
np.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 500000;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), np, "net.pipe://localhost/MyService");
host.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
host.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
host.Open();
```

I can pass about 100 object collection (`ObservableCollection<Customer>`) from 1 application through callback to other app. But if I make it 1000 or greater objects, the following Timeout Exception error occurs.

> The write to the pipe did not complete
>   within the allotted timeout of
>   00:00:00. The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a
>   longer timeout.

What is the fault in my code ? Please help me to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can turn on WCF tracing on both client and server to see some more details about what is going on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx Also depending on complexity of your objects you can set `MaxItemsInObjectGraph`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/11/14/how-to-configure-maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question was also asked and answered here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wcf/thread/38926593-8ea6-481d-8c43-072b73292f6a